# Dynamic CollectionViewHeader Cell Sizing of a complex layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have read multiple answers on StackOverflow but nothing seemed to works or is used for my case.

I have a collectionview header that needs to be self sizing, but the header also contains views that can be hidden with a stackview or not depending on the data.

I don't know how I am suppose to get this to self sizing:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if(section == 0){

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 500)

    }
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
}
```

My header contains multiple views that changes height dynamically because of the stackview.

**Is there a way that I could layout the header then get the height of a view inside the cell then readjust cell size?**

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

first of all your section header is just a UICollectionViewCell or UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader ?

second I think this might help I have a smiler case in my project and it worked for me

https://www.vadimbulavin.com/collection-view-cells-self-sizing/

Comment: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader